# Store webpage as PDF using tasker

Tags: tasker

I am sending a post request to a site.

The output site should be saved as PDF (similar to printing the page), so that I can download many online pages as PDF and store.

No authentication.

```
Example:-
www.website.com/test.php
post params: link=test&test=true
```

Comment: Can you mention your post query as an example? Does the site requires authentication of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, tasker can't convert any web page (or any document) to pdf. An alternative approach can be letting a third party site to make the pdf and then downloading it with tasker.

After a little googling, I found  http://www.web2pdfconvert.com.  This may serve your need.